# Cannot see URI in documentdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am using DocumentDB on Azure, my problem is I am not able to find the URI , when I click the keys, it shows me the primary and the secondary key, but not the URI.

Please help me to find the same

Comment: Can you elaborate? The questions title references DocumentDB, but the question body references SQL Azure. Which product are you using? I assume you are looking for the URI endpoint to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

The URI endpoint should be displayed next to primary and secondary keys on the "Keys" blade.

Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image: DocumentDB Keys Blade]

Please reach out to me w/ your DocumentDB database account name if this is missing for you - andrl AT microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The reason for me not seeing the URI is because I was looking at the storage, we need to create a documentdb ID, and then we can see the both the URI and keys. This is quit confusing, but it is like it.